# yeoman generator creates 200+ MB of node_modules, is that normal?

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman

Is it normal that running
`yo angular` creates over 200MB in the node_modules folder? 
Is this why running the generator takes about 15 minutes or more depending on my internet connection at the time?

```
18:35 $ du -h|grep M|sort -n -r|head
216M    .
211M    ./node_modules
63M ./node_modules/cdnjs-cdn-data/external
63M ./node_modules/cdnjs-cdn-data
30M ./node_modules/bower
29M ./node_modules/bower/node_modules
6.2M    ./node_modules/caniuse-db
5.1M    ./node_modules/rx
4.8M    ./node_modules/jshint
4.4M    ./bower_components
```

Answer (score 2):

The `node_modules` directory does not contain generated code. It is not even specific for yeoman. It contains sources and binaries of nodejs libraries and tools downloaded by [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). And yes - it is often so heavy and downloading it might take some time.

All dependencies are defined in the [`package.json`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/package.json) file of a template (and any other project that uses npm).